# Trust Calendar - 404 Page Not Found?

Tags: trust

This morning I attempted to access the [Trust Calendar](https://trust.salesforce.com/en/trust/calendar/) and have been receiving 404 Page not Found. Does anybody have any insight into this?

It's sort of ironic right, a site you are supposed to trust yet doesn't exist. Hmmmm.......

[image: Trust Calendar - 404]

Comment: How did you get to this page? It looks like the trust site has had a big overhaul. If I look at the status.salesforce.com status page, the calendar on there works fine?

Answer (score 7):

Salesforce recently moved and update there site address.

https://status.salesforce.com/status

Here you can find the calendar
[image]

I think we need to update our bookmark :)

Comment: Yes I did notice by navigating back to the Trust homepage I could relocate the upcoming maintenance dates. This is not a bookmark of my own, I was redirected from a Salesforce Admin Posts [page](https://admin.salesforce.com/3-steps-to-prepare-for-every-salesforce-release). It looks like there may be a lot of redundant links being used on the web, maybe Salesforce could have considered a redirect link on the 404 page similar to the way they are sending you to the homepage.